# Where does this (student) append come from

Tags: python

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,age,grade): #giving the attributes
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.grade=grade

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

class Course:
    def __init__(self,lesson,max_student):#giving attributes
        self.lesson=lesson
        self.max_student=max_student
        self.students=[]

    def add_student(self,student):
        if len(self.students)<self.max_student:
            self.students.append(student) #append(student) from where
            #I don't get where the append(student) get the name from.
            #As above code did't use student.
            return True
        return False

s1=Student('Tim',19,95) #Naming the student
s2=Student('bill',19,75)
s3=Student('jill',19,65)

course1=Course('Math',2)
course1.add_student(s1) #Adding the Student to a list by appending
course1.add_student(s2)

print(course1.students[0].name)
#Will give Tim but how do i print them all at once
#instead of multiple print maybe like a [0:1] but got error
```

Comment: self.students is a list. In Python, elements are added to lists by calling .append()

Comment: my bad really sorry but thanks for the help still

Comment: ok I formatted it one more time

Comment: It seems you added a second question - that should be a separate one, but the answer is to loop over all the students using `for` and print their name.

Comment: i tried for but the print(course1.students[0].name the [ ] how to keep changing it as if i leave blank no name will be printed

Comment: `for student in course1.students:`, `print student.name` (indented)

Comment: for student in course1.students:, print student.name (indented) this work thanks  but why does the for studentz in course1.students print studentz.name can be diiferent spelling as long both are the same does not have to be spell student as its like not related to above code?

Answer (score 1):

- The `append` method is part of Python. It's part of the list class, so all lists have this method (among others). Check the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp). You set `self.students` to an empty **list** in the line `self.students = []`.
- The `student` variable comes from the argument to `add_student`, as you specified here: `def add_student(self,student)`. So, when you call `course1.add_student(s1)`, the `s1` will be `student` inside the method (because for class methods, the first argument `self` is always the class instance itself and doesn't have to be specified in the call).

Comment: the s1 will be student inside the method (because for class methods, the first argument self is always the class instance itself.How does the s1 name 'bill' be added to the append(student) still sry i dont get this part

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question

Comment: In `course1.add_student(s1)` you are calling the class method `add_student(self, student)` on the class instance `course1`. So the first argument `self` is implicity the class instance that you are calling the method on (`course1`), and the second argument `student` is the first one (and in your case the only one) that you explicitly specify (`s1`).

Comment: still dont quite understand how the name is trasfer to the append(student) will try think a while first ty

Comment: When you say "name", do you mean like "Tim"?

Comment: Yup i kno how append workls but i dont get how append(studen) is tim

Comment: In that case the answer is this: 1) You create an instance of `Student` called `s1`, and initialize its properties, including setting the `name` to `'Tim'`. 2) You create an instance of `Course` called `course1`. It has an empty `students` list now (due to `self.students = []`).

Comment: 3) You call `add_student` on `course1` and pass `s1` (the `Student` instance with name "Tim") to it as argument. 4) Inside the `add_student` method, the `student` argument is what you passed in in step 3 - the `Student` instance previously known as `s1`, with name `'Tim'`. 5) You call `self.students.append(student)` to add that `Student` instance to your `self.students` list. The list now contains the `Student` instance also known as `s1` in your outer code, which has the name "Tim" as we saw before.

Comment: yup 'Tim' my bad

Comment: So at that point, `course1.students[0] == s1`, and since `s1.name == 'Tim'`, that means also that `course1.students[0].name == 'Tim'`.

Comment: From what i understand how is the name only apended not  the age and score as well

Comment: `s1` is appended. The whole object. You can of course also write `course1.students[0].age` and get `19`.